# Arduino Replace : with _

Tags: c++, replace, arduino, esp8266

I am messing around with replacing all `:`with `_` in my ESP8266 Mac Address. I tried the `replace()` Method like this:

```
WiFi.macAddress().replace(WiFi.macAddress().begin(),
WiFi.macAddress().end(), ':', '_');
```

But it does not work and throws `'class String' has no member begin`.

I am no C++ pro so maybe you can help me replacing all `:` in the Mac Address with `_`!

Comment: You don't need `.begin()` or `.end()` for replacing in Arduino's `String` class: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringReplace

Comment: @UnholySheep When using `WiFi.macAddress().replace(":","_")` I get `invalid use of 'void'`

Comment: So, checking the [reference for `WiFi.macAddress()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiMACAddress) it doesn't even return a string, it returns a byte array - meaning there are no `:` to replace there. You have to build the string yourself (in which case you can decide what delimiters you want to have, if any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as replace method is void and replaces the characters on fly, you need to get MAC into a variable before manipulating it.

```
String MAC = WiFi.macAddress();
MAC.replace(':', '_');
Serial.println(MAC);
```

Comment: does casting as string like that curtail the need for `WiFi.macAddress().toString()` to get the colons?

Comment: Expanding the statements would be more helpful for begginners. But actually i was not sure about the usage of toString of macAddr. I believe in operator overloading of String :)

Comment: i ask because in JS, `String(x)` invokes `x.toString`; is ardiuno the same?

Comment: From ESP8266WiFiSTA implementation : String  macAddress();

Comment: Also we wouldn't get all toString conversion in C++ if it is not implemented. Does it make sense to you?